# How to remove calendar.js?

Tags: javascript, ce-1.9.2.0, calendar

I am trying to remove calendar.js via local.xml but have trouble doing so, can anyone post a correct code for 1.9.2?

My local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            <remove name="return_link"/>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
                <url helper="catalogsearch/getSearchTermUrl"/>
            </action>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
                <url helper="catalogsearch/getAdvancedSearchUrl"/>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
<action method="removeItem">
    <type>js</type>
    <name>calendar/calendar.js</name>
</action>
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping"/>
        <remove name="checkout.cart.coupon"/>
    </checkout_cart_index>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.additional">
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>product_tag_list</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

https://www.airyhair.com/clip-in-hair-extensions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this does the trick:-

```
<action method="removeItem">
    <type>js</type>
    <name>calendar/calendar.js</name>
</action>
```

### Edit

Organise like this:-

```
<default>
    <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>js</type>
            <name>calendar/calendar.js</name>
        </action>
    </block>
    <reference name="footer_links">
        <remove name="return_link"/>
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
            <url helper="catalogsearch/getSearchTermUrl"/>
        </action>
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
            <url helper="catalogsearch/getAdvancedSearchUrl"/>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: Still see it in source

[code]enUS = {"m":{"wide":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],"abbr":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]}}; // en_US locale reference
Calendar._DN = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]; // full day names
Calendar._SDN = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"]; // short day names[/code]

Comment: Did you check to see if `calendar.js` had stopped being loaded after updating the XML? You need to move it to inside the `<default>` block like my answer edit otherwise try renaming the js file and then refresh the frontend to see if the code disappears (just to confirm that it is actually being output from that js file).